# Colors of political parties

Tags: data-request, government

I am working on a project which visualizes html tables automatically.

If the table includes parties, it would be great to have the color for this party. Does anyone know some page,api or something else to get these colors?

For example:

```
Country,Party,Color,Hex Value
US,Republican,Red,FF0000
US,Democratic,Blue,0000FF
```

My project site: http://github.wikunia.de/Table2Chart/

Comment: This looks like a nifty project but what do you mean by "parties"?

Comment: Well in Germany sth. like SPD,CDU in the USA maybe republicans and democrats

Comment: So you're looking for something like [this on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_colour) but structured as `US,Republican,red`, `US,Democrat,blue` (for example?)

Comment: Yes that would be cool and with hex colors or rgb :)

Comment: Hmm, I honestly dont think there will be a better source than Wikipedia for this one. If you go through the work of extracting the information, definitely update your question so others can benefit in the future. The best I could find was a UK-specific spreadsheet here: http://blog.richardallen.co.uk/uk-political-party-web-colours/

Comment: I will parse the Wikipedia article in August and will add a gist for that here or sth like that. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please rename the question to "Colors of political parties"? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list for UK political parties - ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Index_of_United_Kingdom_political_parties_meta_attributes)).

[image]

By doing [similar searches](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=United+States+political+parties+meta+attributes), you can find other lists hosted on Wikipedia.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Index_of_Minnesota_political_parties_meta_attributes
```

[image]

I think with a few of these lists you can make a joined list of major parties. Because there are so many parties, the colors will start to overlap and be indistinguishable, so I'd stick to just a few main parties.

Comment: Thanks I will try to generate a JSON file and integrate it into my github project